# Undefined type and Undeclared identifiers in xstring

Tags: c++, header-files, libraries, visual-studio-2019

I've been creating a class that defines an integer in a base other than ten. Today when I tried to compile I got a long list of errors in xstring which seemed to mostly be undefined type errors or undeclared identifier errors. I was wondering if this is a result of forgetting to include some file or me misusing a string.

intBase.cpp (the class where I would have mishandled a string)

```
#include "intBase.h"

intBase::intBase(int b)
{
    base = b;
    num = 0;
}

intBase::intBase(std::string n, int b)
{
    base = b;
    setNum(n);
}

int intBase::getBase() const
{
    return base;
}

void intBase::setBase(int b)
{
    base = b;
}

std::string intBase::getNum() const
{
    int expo = 0, n, numTemp = num;
    std::string result = "";
    char ch;

    while (num > int(pow(base, expo)))
    {
        expo++;
    }
    expo--;

    while (expo >= 0)
    {
        n = int(numTemp / pow(base, expo));
        ch = convert(n, false);
        numTemp -= int(n * pow(base, expo));
        result += ch;
        expo--;

    }

    return result;
}

void intBase::setNum(std::string n)
{
    char ch;
    int expo, temp;

    num = 0;
    expo = 0;

    while (n.size() > 0)
    {
        ch = n[n.size() - 1];
        temp = convert(ch, true);
        num += int(temp * pow(base, expo));
        expo++;
        n = n.substr(0, n.size() - 1);
    }

}

int intBase::getNumTen() const
{
    return num;
}

void intBase::setNumTen(int n)
{
    num = n;
}

intBase intBase::add(const intBase& iBase) const
{
    intBase IB(1);

    if (getBase() > iBase.getBase())
    {
        IB.setBase(base);
    }
    else
    {
        IB.setBase(base);
    }

    IB.setNumTen(getNumTen() + iBase.getNumTen());

    return IB;
}

intBase intBase::operator+(const intBase& iBase) const
{
    return add(iBase);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const intBase& iBase)
{
    output << iBase.getNum();
    return output;
}

// takes a character and returns its base ten conversion if bool is true
// takes a base-ten integer and returns its character conversion if bool is false
int intBase::convert(int x, bool letter) const
{
    int result;

    if (letter)
    {
        if (x >= 48 && x <= 57)
            result = x - 48;
        else if (x >= 97 && x <= 122)
            result = x - 87;
        else if (x >= 65 && x <= 90)
            result = x - 29;
        else
            result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x <= 9)
            result = x + 48;
        else if (x >= 10 && x <= 35)
            result = x + 87;
        else if (x >= 36 && x <= 61)
            result = x + 29;
        else
            result = -1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

intBase.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

class intBase
{
public:
    intBase(int b);
    intBase(std::string n, int b);

    int getBase() const;
    void setBase(int b);
    std::string getNum() const;
    void setNum(std::string n);
    int getNumTen() const;
    void setNumTen(int n);

    intBase add(const intBase& iBase) const;
    intBase operator+(const intBase& iBase) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const intBase& iBase);

private:
    int convert(int x, bool y) const;
    int num, base;
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "intBase.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int base;
    string numTemp;

    cout << "enter the base of your number: ";
    cin >> base;
    intBase num(base);

    cout << "enter a number in base " << base << ": ";
    cin >> numTemp;
    num.setNum(numTemp);

    cout << num.getNumTen() << endl;
    cout << num << endl;
    cout << num + num << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

error log

```
1>------ Build started: Project: numBaseTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>intBase.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(435,23): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(4519): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::_Insert_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,unsigned int>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const _Elem *const ,const _SizeT)' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(4519): message :         with
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(4519): message :         [
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(4519): message :             _Elem=char,
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(4519): message :             _SizeT=unsigned int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(4519): message :         ]
1>E:\college\numBaseTest\numBaseTest\numBaseTest\intBase.cpp(104): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(435,1): error C2065: 'iostate': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(435,31): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '_State'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(435,31): error C2065: '_State': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(435,49): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(435,1): error C2065: 'goodbit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(438,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(441,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(444,29): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(444,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(444,36): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '_Ok'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(444,36): error C3861: '_Ok': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(446,10): error C2065: '_Ok': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(447,9): error C2065: '_State': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(447,28): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(447,1): error C2065: 'badbit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(450,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(450,39): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(450,1): error C2065: 'adjustfield': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(450,64): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(450,1): error C2065: 'left': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(452,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(452,1): error C2660: 'std::_Narrow_char_traits<char,int>::eq_int_type': function does not take 1 arguments
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(401,38): message : see declaration of 'std::_Narrow_char_traits<char,int>::eq_int_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(453,21): error C2065: '_State': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(453,40): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(453,1): error C2065: 'badbit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(459,13): error C2065: '_State': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(459,32): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(459,1): error C2065: 'goodbit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(460,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(461,13): error C2065: '_State': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(461,32): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(461,1): error C2065: 'badbit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(464,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(464,1): error C2660: 'std::_Narrow_char_traits<char,int>::eq_int_type': function does not take 1 arguments
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(401,38): message : see declaration of 'std::_Narrow_char_traits<char,int>::eq_int_type'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(465,21): error C2065: '_State': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(465,40): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(465,1): error C2065: 'badbit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(471,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(472,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(472,9): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(472,1): error C2065: 'badbit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(475,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\iosfwd(216): message : see declaration of 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
1>test.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\xstring(475,20): error C2065: '_State': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "numBaseTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thank you for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an include to sstream. Add it to the top of intBase.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: Sorry for disturbing a years old answer. But how did you get to this conclusion?

The error messages all look like ostream could not be found which would lead me to including `<ostream>` or `<iostream>`

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue has been raised in the Visual Studio Developer Community.
It explains: This is by design and has removed the iostreams entry from the string.

[Visual Studio answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-compilation-issue/525532)